# Facebookexternalhit causes Range Not Satisfiable error

Tags: node.js, facebook, error-handling

I have a NodeJS server that sometimes throws a `RangeNotSatisfiableError: Range Not Satisfiable` error. Looking at the logs, the call that is always behind it has user-agent `facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)`, whether it is on pages with streaming media (such as https://emotionathletes.org/) or without it (such as https://emotionathletes.org/login).

Why does the Facebook crawler request ranges out of reach?

**Update**: I added logging details for these requests. The range requested is always from 0 to 2^19 - 1. They happen on a public page such as [www.emotionathletes.org/miguel](http://www.emotionathletes.org/miguel). The stdout log show:

```
[2021-03-26T09:29:48.451Z] /miguel  ::  facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)
[2021-03-26T09:29:48.451Z] bytes=0-524287
[0mGET /miguel [32m200[0m 5.490 ms - 14652[0m
[2021-03-26T09:29:48.475Z] /miguel  ::  facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)
[2021-03-26T09:29:48.475Z] bytes=0-524287
[0mGET /miguel [32m200[0m 3.530 ms - 14652[0m
[0mGET /javascripts/main.js [33m416[0m 1.257 ms - 148[0m
[0mGET /javascripts/main.js [32m200[0m 0.495 ms - -[0m
[2021-03-26T09:29:49.306Z] /miguel  ::  facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)
[2021-03-26T09:29:49.306Z] bytes=0-524287
[0mGET /miguel [32m200[0m 4.592 ms - 14442[0m
[2021-03-26T09:29:49.613Z] /miguel  ::  facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)
[2021-03-26T09:29:49.613Z] bytes=0-524287
[0mGET /miguel [32m200[0m 5.411 ms - 14442[0m
[0mGET /images/logo_1200x630_shared_image_PT.png [32m200[0m 0.519 ms - 87137[0m
[2021-03-26T09:29:51.002Z] /miguel  ::  facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)
[2021-03-26T09:29:51.002Z] bytes=0-524287
[0mGET /miguel [32m200[0m 4.482 ms - 14652[0m
[2021-03-26T09:29:54.190Z] /miguel  ::  facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)
[2021-03-26T09:29:54.190Z] bytes=0-524287
[0mGET /miguel [32m200[0m 5.366 ms - 14652[0m
[2021-03-26T09:29:54.212Z] /miguel  ::  facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)
[2021-03-26T09:29:54.212Z] bytes=0-524287
```

The error log shows only one entry for these events:

```
[2021-03-26T09:29:48.604Z] RangeNotSatisfiableError: Range Not Satisfiable
    at SendStream.error (/home/bitnami/emotionathletes/server/node_modules/send/index.js:270:31)
    at SendStream.send (/home/bitnami/emotionathletes/server/node_modules/send/index.js:670:19)
    at onstat (/home/bitnami/emotionathletes/server/node_modules/send/index.js:729:10)
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:167:5)
[2021-03-26T11:30:09.714Z] (something else...)
```

**Second update**: I fixed the circular warning per the comments. Facebook keeps requesting bytes `0-524287` on pages such as /404, /escolas, /testimonials, /register, etc, but not all throw this error. If the page is requested in quick succession, the server only throws one error.

Is it possible to add debugging to the error handler to trace the page causing the error?

Comment: What range _did_ it request?

Comment: @CBroe I added such details in the logs and will report the results here next time I get this error.

Comment: @CBroe It happened again and I added details.

Comment: Loading that example URL /miguel in the browser, shows a `Content-Length: 14446` in the response headers. That the server doesn’t know how to serve the bytes from `0-524287` in that situation, is understandable. Question would then be, what makes the Facebook scraper request this range in the first place.

Comment: I just put the URL through the FB debug tool, that said it hadn’t been shared before, and after triggering a scrape, it shows a problem with a circular redirect path, https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.emotionathletes.org%2Fmiguel So if you want sharing on Facebook to work, you’ll need to resolve that problem first of all.

Comment: @CBroe Yes, I changed the handle for privacy to my own handle, but it works just the same. I just tested the Facebook debugger on that link and I get `Response code: 200` after 5 redirects. I get a warning about `og:type, fb:app_id`, which I don't have and should not be a problem.

Comment: That’s not the only warning, if you show all, you should also see _“Circular Redirect: We could not resolve the canonical URL because the redirect path contained a cycle.”_

Comment: Yes, you are right, and I fixed that now along with `og:type`. In the next few weeks I'll know if that was causing the problem.

Comment: @CBroe That did not fix it and I still get this error. I dug deeper, added a second update, and am now even more confused...